# Javascript returned data from function which fetches an api

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I have the follwoing function which uses fetch to cal a restfull APi and get the output data which is in text format:

```
async function fetchText(url) {
            let response = await fetch(url);
            let data = await response.text();
            console.log('data...',data);
            return data;
        }
```

The function execution of this script

```
mydata=fetchText(myurl);
console.log("mydata...........",mydata);
```

returns this out put

**mydata........... Promise[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: ""6269A297-851B-4158-873B-66F068B73BCD""
data... "6269A297-851B-4158-873B-66F068B73BCD"**

How to change the function so that its output is exactly what is displayed by the log instead of the Promise type ?

Comment: Any function marked as `async` will _always_ return a `Promise`, there is no way to change that.

Comment: How to retrieve the data from the promise ?

Comment: Same as how you do it already: use `await`. Eg: `mydata = await fetchText(myurl)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function that uses async keyword will always returns promise, so use following code to print value.

`fetchText(myurl).then(data=>{ console.log(data) })`